# Splitting a matrix by both rows and columns using asplit() in R

Tags: r, matrix, split

Consider the following fake example where I extract all comparisons corresponding to a name called `A` from a matrix called `matr`.

```
### Set up example matrix ###
matr <- matrix(c(2,0,3,0,5,0.7,1,0,0.9,6,11,9,0,1,0.5,2,0,1,0.3,3,6,1,0.31,0,0),     nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
dimnames(matr) = list(c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"),  c("A", "B", "A", "C", "A"))
matr

# Pretend the matrix is symmetric - for my real matrix, it is
matr[upper.tri(matr, diag = TRUE)] <- NA # gwt lower triangle
matr

for (rowLoopCounter in 1:nrow(matr)){

  #Get the row of interest
  matr_work <- matr[rowLoopCounter,,drop=FALSE]

  for (colLoopCounter in 1:nrow(matr)) {
    if (row.names(matr)[rowLoopCounter] == colnames(matr)[colLoopCounter]){
      matr[rowLoopCounter, colLoopCounter] <- NA
    }
  }
}

A_row <- c(matr[grepl("A", row.names(matr)), ]) # get comparisions in row
sA_col <- c(matr[, grepl("A", colnames(matr))]) # get comparisions in columns
total <- as.numeric(na.omit(unlist(c(_A_row, A_col)))) # combine results

total
#[1] 0 6 3 0 0 1
```

The above implementation is quite verbose, but only gets the job done for `A`. I need to also do this for `B` and `C`.

This can be done using a `for` loop (or `apply()`).

I naively tried using `split()`, which only works on vectors and gives strange results (leaves out the values 1 in `A` and puts it in `C` for some reason):

```
splt <- split(matr, colnames(matr)) # using rownames(matr) is equivalent

#$A
#[1] NA NA NA NA  0  6 NA NA NA NA NA  3 NA NA NA

#$B
#[1]  0 NA NA NA NA

#$C
#[1] 0.0 0.9 1.0  NA  NA
```

`$A$` should contain the same elements as `total`.

I recently discovered the new `asplit()` function, but I get an error

```
asplit(matr, c(1, 2))
#Error in array(newx[, i], d.call, dn.call) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0
```

**What I would like from `asplit()` is a similar output returned by `split()` where values are stored in named lists. However, from running the examples in the documentation for `asplit()`, there's no way to do this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split()` on both the column and row by swapping the rownames of `which(!is.na(matr), arr.ind=T)`. Then use `mapply()` to combine your two lists.

```
#Get index of matr by its array index, removing NA values
ind<- which(!is.na(matr), arr.ind=T)

#Create a list by factor of row names.
list_1<- split(x = matr[ind], f = row.names(ind))

#Then substitute the column name as the row name. 
row.names(ind)<- colnames(matr)[unname(ind[,2])]

#Create a second list by factor of column name.
list_2<- split(x = matr[ind], f = row.names(ind))
    
#Combine your lists
mapply(c, list_1, list_2)
```

Output of the `mapply()`:

```
$A
[1] 0 6 3 0 0 1

$B
[1] 0.0 0.0 0.9 6.0

$C
[1] 0.0 0.9 1.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

one liner would be:

```
with(na.omit(as.data.frame.table(matr)), split(c(Freq, Freq), c(Var1, Var2)))

$A
[1] 0 6 3 0 0 1

$B
[1] 0.0 0.0 0.9 6.0

$C
[1] 0.0 0.9 1.0 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

not entirely sure what you want to achieve - but if it is a list of vectors, per letter, containing all matrix values where row and column letter coincide, you can do this:

```
library(dplyr) ## for convenient dataframe manipulation
```

```
df <- 
  cbind(
  expand.grid(row = dimnames(matr)[[1]],
              col = dimnames(matr)[[2]]),
  value = as.vector(matr)
)
```

```
#  > head(df)
#    row col value
# 1   A   A   2.0
# 2   B   A   0.0
# 3   A   A   3.0
# 4   C   A   0.0
# 5   A   A   5.0
# 6   A   B   0.7
```

filter above `df` for coinciding row and column letters, and summarise per letter:

```
df <- df |>
  filter(row == col) |>
  group_by(row) |>
  summarise(total = list(value))
```

convert to named list:

```
totals = setNames(df$total, df$row)
```

output:

```
## > totals
## $A
## [1]  2.00  3.00  5.00 11.00  0.00  0.50  6.00  0.31  0.00
## 
## $B
## [1] 1
## 
## $C
## [1] 0.3
```

Comment: Thanks. I notice the output includes all values in `matrix` instead of just those in the lower triangle. Trying your solution on the lower triangular matrix return all `NA`s in the output `totals`. Any reason why and how to fix the issue?

Comment: You could apply `na.omit` to remove these. Anyhow @onyambu has already posted a most elegant answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a followup to @SEAnalyst's great answer.

Since `split()` works on vectors, this is equivalent to rows in a matrix. This would be the output of `list_1`. To generate `list_2`, you could simply `t`ranspose `matr` along with `colnames()`.

The entire implementation would then be

```
# Create a list by factor of row names.
list_1 <- split(matr, colnames(matr))

# Create a second list by factor of column name.
list_2 <- split(t(matr), colnames(t(matr)))

# Combine your lists
splt <- mapply(c, list_1, list_2)

# Get rid of NAs
splt <- lapply(splt, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
```

Easier to understand I think.